# Why would IE8 send IE9/MSIE 9.0 as its user agent (see screenshot)

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I have IE8 on Vista, yet IE8 reports its user agent as IE9.

In developer view, IE8 shows at the browser...

[image]

Comment: This belongs to superuser or web. This has nothing in relation with programming.

Comment: Try running with extensions disabled (Win+R "iexplore.exe -extoff"). It may be that an extension is causing this.

Comment: Is it possible that IE9 was once installed on this machine and later uninstalled?  If so, there's a small possibility that certain registry keys were left behind.

As of IE8, the Trident token (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537503(v=vs.85).aspx#TriToken) is the preferred way to identify the version of the browser...in those cases where the browser must be identified. 

If memory serves, IE8 has troubles with user-agent strings larger than a certain number of characters (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2009/01/09/the-internet-explorer-8-user-agent-string-updated-edition.aspx).

Comment: @lleonard Good idea about IE 9 once being installed. You must know a thing or two about IE/Windows ;)

Comment: Yeah, you could say I have a bit of experience.  Know anyone who's hiring?  I'm available.  ;-)

Comment: It's possible IE9 was installed before... I'll check and let you know.